# Function argument value saved even after function has closed

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, tree

The following code is part of a tree data structure im trying to make. I call this function once then once it finishes i call it again and somehow the value of visitednodes is saved across calls.

```
def print_nodes(self, currentnode=None, visitednodes=[]):
        if currentnode == None:
            print(visitednodes)
            currentnode = self.root
        print(currentnode.depth, currentnode.data, currentnode.parent)
        visitednodes.append(currentnode)
        if currentnode.children == []:
            return visitednodes
        for child in currentnode.children:
            if child in visitednodes:
                continue
            visitednodes = self.print_nodes(child, visitednodes)
        return visitednodes
```

I tried just setting the value of visitednodes to an empty list in the second call which did solve the problem but i dont want to have to set it to an empty list every time i call the function.